# Constants for a solution to the Laplace equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Consider one of the solutions to the Laplace equation 
$$u(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} C_{n}e^{-\alpha _{n}^2kt}\left [ \frac{-\alpha_{n} }{h}\cos(\alpha _{n}x) + B_{n}\sin(\alpha _{n}x) \right ],$$
where 
$\alpha _{n}^2$ is a positive eigenvalue.  An initial condition is given as 
$$u(x,0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C_{n}\left [ \frac{-\alpha_{n} }{h}\cos(\alpha _{n}x) + B_{n}\sin(\alpha _{n}x) \right ].$$

I am not showing my work that got me to this solution, because that would be a bit of time waster, both for me and whoever is reading.

My question is:

> From this information, what would be the constants(usually given as an expression with an integral) of $C_{n}$ and $B_{n}$?

I usually do not have trouble with this, but the $C_{n}$ seems to be where I am confused.  I understand that this would  be a full Fourier seires, but I am not too sure how to continue.  Could anyone provide me some feedback?

Thanks in advance!

Edit: The boundary conditions are: 
$$u_{x}(0,t) +hu(0,t)=0 \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \  u_{x}(1,t)=0, t>0.$$
Also, I am just showing the solution for the positive eigenvalues, since I do not need help finding the constants for the negative one.

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?

Comment: @carsandpulsars Added!

Comment: For determining the coefficients, the boundary of $x$ is important from the orthogonality relations, is it $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not including that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start off with the eigenfunction in $x$

$$ X_n(x) = -\frac{\alpha_n}{h}\cos(\alpha_n x) + B_n\sin(\alpha_n x) $$

The first B.C. gives

$$ X_n'(0) + hX_n(0) = \alpha_n B_n - \alpha_n = 0 \implies B_n = 1 $$

With that out of the way, the second B.C. gives

$$ X_n'(1) = \alpha_n\left[\frac{\alpha_n}{h}\sin \alpha_n + \cos\alpha_n\right] = 0 $$

$$ \implies \alpha_n\tan\alpha_n = -h $$

This is a necessary condition for $\alpha_n$. There is no closed form, but you can solve it numerically given any $h$.

---

To show the eigenfunctions are orthogonal, note that for $n\ne m$ we have

$$ \int_0^1 {X_m}''X_n = {X_m}'X_n\Bigg|_0^1 - X_n{X_m}'\Bigg|_0^1 + \int_0^1 X_m{X_n}'' $$

However

\begin{align} 
{X_m}'X_n\Bigg|_0^1 - X_n{X_m}'\Bigg|_0^1 &= -{X_m}'(0)X_n(0) + X_m(0){X_n}'(0) \\
&= hX_m(0)\cdot X_n(0) - X_m(0)\cdot hX_n(0) = 0
\end{align}

Therefore

$$ \int_0^1 {X_m}''X_n - \int_0^1 X_m{X_n}'' = 0 \implies -(\alpha_m^2-\alpha_n^2)\int_0^1 X_mX_n = 0 $$

But $\alpha_m \ne \alpha_n$, so the integral must be $0$

---

The remaining condition is

$$ u(x,0) = f(x) = \sum_n C_n X_n(x) $$

where $f(x)$ is a known function. Using orthogonality

$$ \int_0^1 f(x)X_m(x) dx = \sum_n C_n \int_0^1 X_n(x) X_m(x) dx = C_m \int_0^1 \big[X_m(x)\big]^2\ dx $$

$$ \implies C_n = \frac{\int_0^1 f(x) X_n(x)\ dx}{\int_0^1 \big[X_n(x)\big]^2\ dx} $$

where the integrals depend on $\alpha_n$. Again, numerical computation is useful here

---

If you follow the same method for the other case, i.e. $X'' = \mu^2 X$, you'll find

$$ X_n(x) = \frac{\mu_n}{h}\cosh(\mu_n x) + \sinh(\mu_n x) $$

and $ \mu_n\tanh\mu_n = h $. There is one solution if $h > 0$.

Note that the formula for $C_n$ works the same whether the eigenvalue is positive, negative, or zero.